# Non-orthogonality of a number of vectors exceeding the dimension of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

A basic fact in linear algebra is that an N-dimensional vector space can have at most N linearly independent vectors. Is there a better statement of non-orthogonality when there are more vectors than dimensions? This is the best I could derive:
Suppose $v_1\dots v_M$ are $M$ normalized vectors in $\mathbb{R}^N$ (that is, $v_i\cdot v_i = 1$ for all $i$), and $M \geq N$. Define
$$f = \sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j=1}^M(v_i\cdot v_j)^2 . $$
Then $f\geq \frac{M^2}{N}$.

Comment: I think you expression is $\|V^TV\|_F^2$, right?

Comment: Maybe look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013922/constructing-an-epsilon-net-of-l-2-unit-ball

Comment: Yes, that's correct, its $\|V^T V\|_F^2$